# Menu visibility

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created the menu with visibility expression with property tester as follow:

```
        <menu
              label="Recent projects">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
              <test
                    property="VisibilityTester">
              </test>
           </visibleWhen>
        </menu>
```

it is works. But the method "test()" in the property tester class, platform calls not every time when it is necessary. In result, sometimes this menu is visible when it must not be visible and on the contrary.

How to force the platform to call these methods programmically when it is necessary to refreshing the state of such menus?

Answer (score 1):

Platform core expression provide 2 methods to provide information for the evaluation.  The first is contributing `ISourceProviders`, which can then be used in the **with** element.  `ISourceProviders` are event driven, updating the system as they change.

The other way is to use property testers.  They are much lighter weight, providing a way to test properties it doesn't make sense to provide as variables.  But as you found, they're not event driven and don't force an update in the system.  But there is API you can use to request their re-evaluation, `org.eclipse.ui.services.IEvaluationService.requestEvaluation(String)`.

```
IEvaluationService srv = (IEvaluationService) workbench.getService(IEvaluationService.class);
srv.requestEvaluation("org.eclipse.core.resources.persistentProperty");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What method is more preferable?

Comment: Source providers are useful for the current state of the application.  i.e. active window, part, and editor, or the currently logged in user.  Property Testers are good for properties of the source variables or selection (like the persistent property of a resource), or the editor input, or application state that it is not easy to present as a simple set of variables.